# Fire Event or listener after certain time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to Fire Event or listener after certain time in Laravel, my idea is to have one listener for sending mails after one minute, after user registration, cron isnt solution for this case.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a queue, to be honest. You can choose to queue events after a certain period of time.

Comment: hm but can i set time

Comment: Yes, exactly like I wrote...

Comment: i will try with job

Comment: Why are you dismissing cron here? You could run it every minute, and have a command that sends the notification to users registered in the previous minute.

Answer (score 6):

In this case a job would be a better options.  To be honest queued jobs when firing logic within your application is more suited for this kind of logic.

Jobs require less set up to events as you only need a single class, rather than events and listeners.

To delay your job use the following syntax, where SendReminderEmail is your job.  The parameter in the delay function is the number of seconds you wish to delay the process.

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->delay(60);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs

Comment: And if I want to delay for 24 hours, but how can you handle changes of time due timezone and stuff like that? is there a way to set it up with a specific time?

Comment: @pmirnd You can calculate the number of seconds left *until* that time and pass it to `delay()`. Do note the docs' warning that AWS SQS is limited to 15 minute delays at most.